# Rails: Use sanitize_sql_for_conditions without model or db connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Referencing the methods in this doc primarily
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

I have a sql, `id = :id`, and the user input for the binded variables that are coming in that I need to sanitize. `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` works perfectly for my situation. However, it seems that it can only be called through the method or through an active DB connection. Is there a way to the the `sanitize_sql_*` methods without a model or db connection? I know `ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql` works, but I would prefer not to use a deprecated method.

Currently on rails 5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr There's no way to do it without a connection to the database.**

Gonna answer my own question here since I dug through how `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` works. When using `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` with an array input containing the sql and hashes, it ultimately points to [`replace_bind_variable(value, c = connection)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/070d4afacd3e9721b7e3a4634e4d026b5fa2c32c/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L174) which requires a connection to the db in order to determine what `quote` method to use. So no luck here.

Comment: on some level - kind of makes sense.  why are you sanitizing sql without a db connection :D. good find.

Comment: @mrrogers long story short, I have a static db client outside of my rails app and I'm sending the SQL statement to it from rails instead of using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Would you be able to update your answer with information on how to get the connection to the current database? It seems that you're saying it should be possible to use `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` if you can get that, but `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.sanitize_sql_for_conditions` doesn't work.